# Implement this kind of android viiew if possible with Horizontal Bar chart or any week calendar view

Tags: android, bar-chart, android-custom-view, horizontalscrollview

I am recording hour for doing work in one day and want to display that work progress for week like this view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer of my question. I was finding bar instead or draw view on layout. I left that idea and now drawing view on relative layout on specific position and able to getting this view.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_chart_view, null);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height - 1);
        params.leftMargin = leftMargine;
        params.topMargin = topMargine;

        if (isGreen) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green9));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray9));
        }

        rltChart.addView(view, params
```

);